# Python 3.8.1: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' - Is tensorflow only supported up to 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I am using Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10 and am trying to install TensorFlow.

I have tried many methods to install it, but I keep getting the following error upon importing TensorFlow. This time, I installed it using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deep_versions.py", line 6, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\rapto\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

What I have done to try to fix it: I have looked at other similar questions on here but they have been for older versions of Python. I have also looked at [this GitHub post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512) but could not resolve the issue.

I checked the TensorFlow site for Python version compatability but the latest update that I could find was a few months ago, saying that TensorFlow only supports up to Python 3.7 ([https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374) Is this still the case and do I need to downgrade Python in order to use TensorFlow?

Please let me know if there is any more information I should provide (I'm still learning how to correctly ask questions here). Thank you.

Edit: I created a conda environment with Python 3.7 and I did not get the same error and importing TF seems to be working fine now. It seems that Python 3.8 is still not yet supported, so this may have been the problem.

Comment: I created an environment using conda with Python 3.7 and installing TF worked. I still cannot figure out from the TF website if Python 3.8 is supported or not, but if it isn't that probably has something to do with why I was getting this ModuleNotFoundError. I hope this answer to my own question helps anyone who may have had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per the installation documents, only Python 3.5-3.7 are supported. https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the version of python or TensorFlow and You should change versions of either Python or Tensorflow, as these 2 versions you are using are not compatible. You could downgrade to Python3.6 or try Tensorflow>=1.13.1 which supports Python 3.7. it should work hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me, i managed to fix it by creating a venv by using `conda create -n <venv name> python=3.6`. Important to note that the python version specified needs to be 3.6. Then, using the same command just the difference is that i used `tensor-gpu` instead `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu`. Note that my python versio on my machine is 3.7.8, but i guess any versions from 3.5-3.8 should be fine. Hope it still helps someone in the future!